# JavaScript to TypeScript: Intellisense and dynamic members

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a JavaScript object which dynamically allows members to be bound as accessor properties to instances of the object:

**Source**

```
function DynamicObject(obj) {
    for (var prop in obj) {
        Object.defineProperty(this, prop, {
            get: function () { return obj[prop]; },
            set: function (value) { obj[prop] = value; },
            enumerable: true,
            configurable: false
        });
    }
}
```

**Usage**

```
var obj = new DynamicObject({
    name: "John Smith",
    email: "john.smith@test.net",
    id: 1
});
```

When `obj` is created, the members of the constructor parameter are bound to `obj` as accessor properties. These show up in intellisense

[image: Intellisense for dynamic members]

I would like to know if it is possible to model this sort of behavior (including having intellisense) in TypeScript?

**Notes**

When you run this code in TypeScript, there is no intellisense becuase everything is `any`, so TypeScript doesn't really know what's going on.

Comment: I'm curious as to why you would want do this over just using a basic object literal. Just for the `configurable: false`? You could just use `Object.freeze` or `Object.seal` to perform similar tasks...

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan No, the advantages here are actually in the get/set functions, not configurability.

Comment: So, your "real" code does something more interesting with the get/set? That's cool.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I would like to know if it is possible to model this sort of behavior (including having intellisense) in TypeScript?

**Yes.**

You can assign a generic call signature to `DynamicObject`. You'll need to declare it as a variable:

```
var DynamicObject: new <T>(obj: T) => T = function (obj)
{
    for (var prop in obj)
    {
        Object.defineProperty(this, prop, {
            get: function () { return obj[prop]; },
            set: function (value) { obj[prop] = value; },
            enumerable: true,
            configurable: false
        });
    }
} as any;
```

This way, IntelliSense will treat the value returned from `new DynamicObject` as having the same type as the value passed in. Same property names, same property types. You'll get full autocomplete and type-safety.

[Live demo on TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=var%20DynamicObject%3A%20new%20%3CT%3E(obj%3A%20T)%20%3D%3E%20T%20%3D%20function%20(obj)%0D%0A%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20for%20(var%20prop%20in%20obj)%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Object.defineProperty(this%2C%20prop%2C%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20get%3A%20function%20()%20%7B%20return%20obj%5Bprop%5D%3B%20%7D%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20set%3A%20function%20(value)%20%7B%20obj%5Bprop%5D%20%3D%20value%3B%20%7D%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20enumerable%3A%20true%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20configurable%3A%20false%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%20as%20any%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Avar%20obj%20%3D%20new%20DynamicObject(%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20name%3A%20%22John%20Smith%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20email%3A%20%22john.smith%40test.net%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20id%3A%201%0D%0A%7D)%3B%0D%0A)

---

*If you have trouble wrapping your head around that part in the first line, it's the same as writing the following:*

```
// Declare type (only exists during compile-time)
var DynamicObject: new <T>(obj: T) => T;

// Assign value (during runtime)
DynamicObject = function (obj)
{
    ...
} as any;
```

Comment: Any chance you could also make DynamicObject work with TypeScript's inheritance model? (sorry, I know that's a tall ask!)

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you are asking here, but you could try using the `&` operator to define [intersection types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html).

Comment: In your example, you have an implementation for DynamicObject. Is is possible to keep this implementation, and have the ability to do... class SomeSortOfDerivedObject extends DynamicObject { ... } ...can I do that?

Answer (score 5):

You can't. These are completely dynamic properties, added at runtime, so you can't possibly know what they are at compile-time. I would also argue that you don't *want* to know what they are that early; if you have constraints to enforce, they should just be stated on their own (first example below).

If your code depends on a set of accessors, you should put those in the interface or contract directly, because you *know* ahead of time that you expect them and should advertise that. You can use optional properties (with the accessor defined lower) to make that simpler:

```
interface HasSomeProps {
  foo: string;
  bar?: string;
}

class DoesTheProps implements HasSomeProps {
  set foo(value) { 
    // ...
  }
}
```

If you have a bunch of consistent (or semi-consistent) accessors, you can define an indexer on your type like:

```
interface AccessStrings {
  [key: string]: string;
}
```

That does not allow you to restrict the keys. If you want that, you should explicitly list the properties.