# typescript generics assign empty object

Tags: typescript

this is what I want to achieve:

```
interface IFoo { ... }
function extendWithFoo<T extends {}>(x: T = {}): T & IFoo {
 ...
}
```

I'm getting error TS2322: Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'T'.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to Nitzan Tomer's suggestion, you can also introduce a type to restrict the input to object literals only

```
type ObjectLiteral = { [key: string]: any };

interface IFoo {
    resultHasFoo(): void; 
}

function extendWithFoo<T extends ObjectLiteral>(x: T = {} as T): T & IFoo {
    return x as T & IFoo;
}

extendWithFoo(false); // error!

extendWithFoo(123); // error!

var p = extendWithFoo({
    test: "one"
});

p.resultHasFoo(); // works!
```

Take a look at my related post... [JavaScript to TypeScript: Intellisense and dynamic members](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39900015/javascript-to-typescript-intellisense-and-dynamic-members)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
function extendWithFoo<T extends {}>(x: T = {} as T): T & IFoo {
    ...
}
```

But using empty objects is problematic, as it accepts everything:

```
extendWithFoo(3); // ok
extendWithFoo("string"); // ok
extendWithFoo(true); // ok
extendWithFoo({}); // ok
extendWithFoo({ key: "value" }); // ok
extendWithFoo(new Array()); // ok
```

So my recommendation is to use something more specific.
In any case, you don't really need it, you can just:

```
function extendWithFoo<T>(x: T = {} as T): T & IFoo {
    ...
}
```

Which gives you the same thing.