# make typescript know all keys from `require.context` of webpack

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

A relative question is https://stackoverflow.com/a/53015011/2326199

The answer by @jcalz works great when all keys are hard coded. But I wonder if it's possible without hard code like using `require.context` of webpack.

Here's [repo](https://github.com/maple-leaf/nextjs-start-kit) demonstrate what I want:

- all svg icons are required at `components/icon.tsx`
- all svg name are exported as `ICONS` from `components/icon.tsx`
- I **should able to receive auto-complete hint** when typing `ICONS.` at `index.tsx`, for this repo, it should give `Bluetoothon` and `Close`

Comment: I'd encourage you to produce a [mcve] in your question if you want a useful answer.  At first glance I'd say that there's no way to do what you're asking for without manually annotating `icons`.  Maybe someone else knows a way for the type system to do this?  Possibly some build step that reads the filenames in a directory and generates types from them?

Comment: yes, do dirty work at build step could be a solution. If it can work directly would be awesome. :-) will try to dig more on this

Answer (score -1):

### You may try this ...
Having many json files under /locales directory.
To load all the messages from a particular locale based on user's choice.

```
function loadLocaleMessages() {
  const locales = require.context(
    "./locales",
    true,
    /[A-Za-z0-9-_,\s]+\.json$/i
  );

  const messages = {};
  locales.keys().forEach((key) => {
    const matched = key.match(/([A-Za-z0-9-_]+)\./i);
    if (matched && matched.length > 1) {
      const locale = matched[1];
      messages[locale] = locales(key);
    }
  });
  return messages;
}
```