# Typescript transform indexed object literal without losing intellisense

Tags: typescript, generics, dynamic, key

I can't seem to figure out the magic incantation to keeping intellisense working between an indexed object literal I'm using to define CSS rules and the returned object from my css generating function that consumes that object.

Here's my psuedo code:

```
type Style = { [key: string]: [keyof CSSStyleDeclaration, string] };

const GenerateCss = (css: Style) => {
  // ...generate css and return an object like this:
  // {
  //   smallFont: 'smallFont',
  //   bigFont: 'bigFont'
  // }
};

const css: Style = {
  smallFont: ['fontSize', '12px'],
  bigFont: ['fontSize', '18px'],
};
```

Result:
I need the typing on `css` so I get the intellisense of various `CSSStyleDeclaration` but then I lose the intellisense for the resulting keys on `css`. I feel like the answer is here: [JavaScript to TypeScript: Intellisense and dynamic members](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39900015/javascript-to-typescript-intellisense-and-dynamic-members) but can't seem to refactor it and make it work.

Answer (score 0):

```
export const style = <T>(
  rules: {
    [key in keyof T]: [keyof CSSStyleDeclaration, string];
  }
): {
  [key in keyof T]: keyof CSSStyleDeclaration;
} => {
  const css: any = {};
  const styles: string[] = [];
  Object.entries(rules).forEach(([k, v]: [string, Atom]) => {
    const declaration = `.${k}{${(<string>v[0])
      .replace(/([A-Z])/g, '-$1')
      .toLowerCase()}:${v[1]}}`;
    css[k] = k;
    styles.push(declaration);
  });
  CreateStyleSheet(styles.join(''));
  return css;
};
```

and

```
const styles = style({
  cursor_pointer: ['cursor', 'pointer'],
  fs_l: ['fontSize', '18px'],
  fs_m: ['fontSize', '16px'],
  fs_xl: ['fontSize', '24px'],
});
```

works, feel free to comment.